# How can I catch any error and get the error itself in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

I want to catch **any** error and get the **error itself**

It's possible to get the error of specific type

```
try:
  raise newException(CatchableError, "some error")
except IOError as e:
  echo e.msg
```

And it's possible to get any error, but the special function need to be called to get the error which feels really wrong

```
try:
  raise newException(CatchableError, "some error")
except:
  let e = getCurrentException()
  echo e.msg
```

Is there a way to do it like:

```
try:
  raise newException(CatchableError, "some error")
except e:
  echo e.msg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any catchable error should extend `CatchableError`, so this should do what you want:

```
try:
  raise newException(IOError, "some error")
except CatchableError as e:
  echo e.msg
```

Comment: Thanks, that should be enough for me. Although it feels a bit over over-complicated, if you can't catch anything other than CatchableErrors anyway, would be better to use shorter notation `except e:`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
try:
  yourCodeHere()
except Exception as e:
  echo e.msg
```

Another answer suggested `CatchableError`.  I don't claim to know why, but I've encountered errors which are not caught that way, but which are caught by `Exception`.

Comment: Specifically, my program was crashing with: `Error: unhandled exception: index out of bounds, the container is empty [IndexDefect]` and the exception handler started working when I replaced `CatchableError` with `Exception`.